# In Scala is there a way to reference the Companion Object from within an instance of a Case Class?

Tags: scala, inheritance

In my specific case I have a (growing) library of case classes with a base trait (`TKModel`)

Then I have an abstract class (`TKModelFactory[T <: TKModel]`) which is extended by all companion objects.

So my companion objects all inherently know the type ('T') of "answers" they need to provide as well as the type of objects they "normally" accept for commonly implemented methods. (If I get lazy and cut and paste chunks of code to search and destroy this save my bacon a lot!) I do see warnings on the Internet at large however that any form of `CompanionObject.method(caseClassInstance: CaseClass)` is rife with "code smell" however. Not sure if they actually apply to Scala or not?

There does not however seem to be any way to declare anything in the abstract case class (`TKModel`) that would refer to (at runtime) the proper companion object for a particular instance of a case class. *This results in my having to write (and edit) a few method calls that I want standard in each and every case class.*

`case class Track(id: Long, name: String, statusID: Long) extends TKModel`

`object Track extends TKModelFactory[Track]`

How would I write something in `TKModel` such that `new Track(1, "x", 1).someMethod()` could actually call `Track.objectMethod()`

Yes I can write `val CO = MyCompanionObject` along with something like  `implicit val CO: ???` in the `TKModel` abstract class and make all the calls hang off of that value. Trying to find any incantation that makes the compiler happy for that however seems to be mission impossible. And since I can't declare that I can't reference it in any placeholder methods in the abstract class either.

Is there a more elegant way to simply get a reference to a case classes companion object?

My specific question, as the above has been asked before (but not yet answered it seems), is there a way to handle the inheritance of both the companion object and the case classes and find the reference such that I can code common method calls in the abstract class?

Or is there a completely different and better model?

Comment: AFAIK, not without reflection. When you say `TKModelFactory[Track]`, `Track` is the *type Track*. But in `object Track`, Track is just a name. You can do the former because *type Track* is defined before.

Comment: Why must it be `Track.objectMethod()` and not `TKModelFactory.objectMethod()`? Is it because you override TKModelFactory's method in your object? If that's the case, you can perhaps call `TKModelFactory.objectMethod` but pass the `Track` instance to take advantage of polymorphism.

Comment: If you also want (sort of) open extension; you can use a type class.

Answer (score 3):

If you change `TKModel` a bit, you can do

```
abstract class TKModel[T <: TKModel] {
  ...
  def companion: TKModelFactory[T]
  def someMethod() = companion.objectMethod()
}

case class Track(id: Long, name: String, statusID: Long) extends TKModel[Track] {
  def companion = Track
}
object Track extends TKModelFactory[Track] {
  def objectMethod() = ...
}
```

This way you do need to implement `companion` in each class. You can avoid this by implementing `companion` using reflection, something like (untested)

```
lazy val companion: TKModelFactory[T] = {
  Class.forName(getClass.getName + "$").getField("MODULE$").
    get(null).asInstanceOf[TKModelFactory[T]]
}
```

`val` is to avoid repeated reflection calls.

Comment: This answer was difficult for me to interpret because it left out the implementation of `TKModelFactory`. I decided to model it within Scastie to get it to a compilable state: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xRZhvznwQaWCHMp0Gy2jZw

Answer (score 2):

A companion object does not have access to the instance, but there is no reason the case class can't have a method that calls the companion object.

```
case class Data(value: Int) {
  def add(data: Data) = Data.add(this,data)
}

object Data {
  def add(d1: Data, d2: Data): Data =  Data(d1.value + d2.value)
}
```

Comment: True - however you must explicitly name that call to the companion object. What I'm trying to do is write something in the parent (base class `TKModel`) that is inherited by all instances of future `TKModel`s and which calls all future `TKModelFactory` companion objects -- and I do not have a reference to them nor a way to abstractly reference them (that I know of) for that call.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult. However you can create an implicit method in companion object. whenever you want to invoke your logic from instance, just trigger implicit rules and the implicit method will instantiate another class which will invoke whatever logic you desired.
I believe it's also possible to do this in generic ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this syntax as an extension method by defining an implicit class in the top-level abstract class that the companion objects extend:

```
abstract class TKModelFactory[T <: TKModel] {
  def objectMethod(t: T)

  implicit class Syntax(t: T) {
    def someMethod() = objectMethod(t)
  }
}
```

A call to `new Track(1, "x", 1).someMethod()` will then be equivalent to `Track.objectMethod(new Track(1, "x", 1))`.